# Postgresql - Renaming the key of all objects in an array of a JSON column

Tags: json, postgresql

PostgreSQL 13

The goal is to rename all `src` keys in the `photos` array to `image`.

I have a table `plans` which has a column `json` with a simplified structure similar to the below sample.

```
{
  "id": "some id",
  "name": "some name",
  "tags": [
    {
      "keyId": 123,
      "valueId": 123
    },
    {
      "keyId": 123,
      "valueId": 123
    }
  ],
  "score": 123,
  "photos": [
    {
      "src": "someString"
    },
    {
      "src": "someString"
    }
  ],
  "payment": true
}
```

The number of objects in the `photos` array varies, but in general, it is less than 10, so a non-iterating method would be fine, too.

I tried something like this, but it is only good for modifying the value of a key, not the name of the key itself.

```sql
UPDATE
    plans
SET
    json = jsonb_set(json::jsonb, '{photos, 0, src}', '"image"')
;
```

With the following attempt, I was actually able to rename the key but it overwrites everything else, so only an object with `{"image": "someUrl"}` is left:

```sql
UPDATE
    plans
SET
    json = (json -> 'photos' ->> 0)::jsonb - 'src' || jsonb_build_object ('image',
        json::jsonb -> 'photos' -> 0 -> 'src')
WHERE json::jsonb ? 'photos' = true;
```

Is there a way to rename keys as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I used a variation of my initial `jsonb_set` method. The solution isn't elegant or efficient, but since it is a one-time operation, it was only important to work:

```sql
UPDATE
    plans
SET
    json = jsonb_set(json::jsonb, '{photos, 0, imageUrl}', (json->'photos'->0->'src')::jsonb)
WHERE
    json->'photos'->0->'src' IS NOT NULL
;
```

This query would add the `imageUrl` key with the existing value of the `src` key for the first object (position 0) in the `photos` array. So it left me with `src` and `imageUrl` key.

To remove the `src` key, I ran the following query

```sql
UPDATE
    plans
SET
    json = json::jsonb #- '{ photos, 0, src}'
;
```

Repeating this as many times as the maximum number of elements in a `photos` array eventually solved the issue for me.